# how to change the color

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In the [**jQuery UI accordion**](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible), when all the accordions are collapsed, the mouse over the collapsed accordions display in a different color.

Current color is very subtle  and hard to notice the mouse over for some of my users.

How to change that color?
Which and where is the CSS property to be changed?

Comment: `jquery-ui.css` line `821`. Maybe handy: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements

Comment: the hover css is defined by .ui-state-hover at line 838 of jquery-ui.css, however the hover color you are having issue with is an image overlay. If you want something more contrasting, change the image to something else or remove it and change the background color.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to change the `ui-state-hover` css property.  You can manually change it in your css file, or simply go to the [theme roller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) on the jquery site and tweak the `Clickable: hover state` - or select a different color scheme or make one entirely on your own.  (Then you'll just have to replace the existing css file with the one you'll create.)

Answer (score 0):

Using Google Chrome developer tools you can see that when hovering of the elements it siwtches classes between `ui-state-default` from jQuery-ui.css line 821 and `ui-state-hover` from line 838 in the same file.

The CSS is:

```
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3/*{borderColorDefault}*/;
    background: #e6e6e6/*{bgColorDefault}*/ url(images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png)/*{bgImgUrlDefault}*/ 50%/*{bgDefaultXPos}*/ 50%/*{bgDefaultYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgDefaultRepeat}*/;
    font-weight: normal/*{fwDefault}*/;
    color: #555555/*{fcDefault}*/;
}
```

and

```
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
    border: 1px solid #999999/*{borderColorHover}*/;
    background: #dadada/*{bgColorHover}*/ url(images/ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400.png)/*{bgImgUrlHover}*/ 50%/*{bgHoverXPos}*/ 50%/*{bgHoverYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgHoverRepeat}*/;
    font-weight: normal/*{fwDefault}*/;
    color: #212121/*{fcHover}*/;
}
```

I would assume that if you have a reference to that css file you can either update it directly in your own copy or add your own css with the same class names adding `!important` to your styles.

I would try the first and I'm not sure the later, using `!important` is good practice, though I could be wrong on that.